# Gatling test that uses a different action every request

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

We're trying to stress test our REST-ish app with Gatling. We want our `users` to make a post with a different `fileBody` every request.

Our scenario looks like:

```scala
scenario("100%")
    .during(15 minutes) {
        exec(requestStream.next())
        .pause(118 seconds, 120 seconds)
    }
    .users(2)
    .delay(2 minutes)
    .protocolConfig(httpConf)

...build up several scenarios...

setUp(severalScenarios)
```

This runs fine but it appears that the block with the `exec` is only executed one time when each scenario is built for the first time. We thought that the block would be executed every time the `during(...)` loop comes around giving each user a new `Request` from the iterator to run every 15 minutes.

Are we missing something? Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not the way the DSL works. The DSL elements are actually builders that are resolved once and for all when the simulation is loaded.

What you want is inject dynamic data into your scenario elements, and you have to use Feeders, user Session, Gatling EL, etc. What does your requestStream look like?

Comment: We were having some trouble with Feeders which drove us down this path, but after a little more hacking and it looks like it works now.